# WPF BeginInvoke and EntityFramework

Tags: wpf, null, begininvoke

I have a search through database. Search works in separate thread.
When entity is found I have to show it and some of related data into WPF UI.

I use EntityFramework. Main idea of search process is:

```
foreach (var item in _currentEntitySet)
{     
    Items.Add(item);
    OnItemFound(item);
}
```

Where `_currentEntitySet` is an `ObjectQuery`

But I have met some problems. When `OnItemFound` is fired, I try to use `BeginInvoke()` to display found item and some related object in UI.

```
    private void OnCatalogueItemFound(CatalogueItem item)
    {
        Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action<object>((param) =>
        {                
            var model = new CatalogueResultItemViewModel(param as CatalogueItem);
            TitlesResultViewModel.Add(model);
        }), System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Background, item);
    }
```

The problem is that navigation properties of **item** are **NULL**

When I use `Invoke()` instead of `BeginInvoke()` then things works fine. 
I have to use exactly `BeginInvoke()` because of some other reasons.

Does anyone knows how can I use `BeginInvoke()` in my situation? Thanks :)

Comment: You may need to use eager loading using the Include method or explicit loading using the Load method.  Not sure why you would have to do this but it's worth a shot.  If nothing at all, this will at least eliminate lazy loading as a possible issue.

Comment: I can, but I dont like solution on data access layer :) I would like to understand why Invoke() works and BeginInvoke() doesnt. Load() and Include() is last solution

Comment: Well I'm not providing as a solution.  Sometimes to find the answer you need to narrow down the problem.  If Include and/or Load eliminate the problem, we know it's a lazy loading issue and can start there.  If it doesn't we know it's not a lazy loading issue and can eliminate it.  Which is why I provided it as a comment and not a solution :).

Comment: @Renatus: The "solution on the data access layer" is the right one - it's the data access layer, so it should be the only layer that touches the data store. After you hand off data to the view layer to be processed at some later point in time, you shouldn't expect it to be able to query the database in the background, even if the query is done automagically by EF. Essentially, even though it's onerous, you should code your app as if there was a big man of a stereotypically frightening ethnicity between layers of your app, holding a web service in his hands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that this may be because you are generating your object with a lambda function.

BeginInvoke is called asynchroimously and possibly by the time it is actioned the object locatedis no longer in scope.

By using Invoke you force the call to be performed synchronously, when the object is still in scope.